# Pandas how work out updates between two DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I’m trying to code something that can check between two dataframes and let me know what's different between the two. Unfortunately, I’ve hit a block and don’t know how to code a solution and was hoping someone could help me out..

The dataframes are populated from two CSV files. The structure of each csv is the same, just the data is different. There are 5 columns and the column names are identical in each dataframe.

The first dataframe `df1` is latest data, the other dataframe `df2` is existing data. I’m trying to work out:

1. New rows added in `df1`.
2. Rows missing `df1` that were in `df2`.
3. Rows that are present in both dataframes, but a value has
   changed.

The way I’ve been approaching this is to create a third dataset `df3` and create a merge of `df1` & `df2` using the following code:

```
 df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, indicator=True,
                on=["A","B","C","D","E"], how="outer")
```

This gives me a `_merge` column and I can create two new datasets using the following code

```
df4 = df3.loc[df3['_merge'] == 'left_only']
df5 = df3.loc[df3['_merge'] == 'right_only']
```

At this point, in `df4`, I have a list of rows which are either genuine new rows, or existing rows which have modified values.
I’m stuck on how to work out which is which?

The data consists of 5 columns, only column `D` will ever change.
I was thinking about looping through each row of `df4` and somehow checking if a row is present in `df5` where columns `A,B,C and E` all match? At that point I can mark the row in `df4` as an `update` and not a `new` row.

I’d really appreciate the help if someone would let me know the correct way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You realize that without a fixed index, or unique row identifier there cannot be a well-defined notion of row in the sense of 'row in df1 is missing in df2' or 'new rows in df1'

Comment: if you want to loop through the rows you could ```for row in df.values: if row in dff.values: print row```.   Could you show an example of both dataframes? print head or something similar.

Comment: thanks for the input, I've attached a pic to my original post to help if possible. In the first row, Column D (Net Short Position (%)" has been increased. The last row is a new entry. There is also a row removed from df1(last row of df2)

I'd like to get to a point where I compare df1 to df2 and output 

X rows have been added (row details)
X rows have been modified (row details)
X rows have been removed (row details)